# LTspice buck converter

Tags: ltspice

I made a buck converter using LTspice.

Vds was plotted like this. What's the problem with this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why do you apply 400V to a gate-source of an NMOS? The pulse generator is already source-referenced. Change the on-voltage to something between 10-15V.

Comment: What is red?  What is green?

Comment: red is Vds and green is Vout

Comment: Thnak you Rohat, it worked

Answer (score 0):

The circuit isn't stable. There are a few things that could improve stability.

1. Reference the voltage source attached to the MOSFET gate from ground instead of the diode
2. Install parasitics on all passives. Real life components have resistance capacitance and inductance. The capacitor should have series resistance. The inductor should have series resistance. You can right click on the components and select from a list of real life components where you can put in the parasitics yourself.